# Dynamically create new columns in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table in R and want to create a new column. Let's say that I have the date column name saved as a variable and want to append `_year` to that name in the new column. I'm able to do that the normal route by just specifying the name, but how can I create the new column name using the `date_col` variable.

Here is what I've tried. The last two, which I want, don't work.

```
dat = data.table(one = 1:5, two = 1:5, 
                 order_date = lubridate::ymd("2015-01-01","2015-02-01","2015-03-01",
                           "2015-04-01","2015-05-01"))
dat
date_col = "order_date"
dat[,`:=`(OrderDate_year = substr(get(date_col)[!is.na(get(date_col))],1,4))][]
dat[,`:=`(new = substr(noquote(get(date_col))[!is.na(noquote(get(date_col)))],1,4))][]
dat[,`:=`(paste0(date_col, "_year", sep="") = substr(noquote(get(date_col))[!is.na(noquote(get(date_col)))],1,4))][]
dat[,`:=`(noquote(paste0(date_col, "_year", sep="")) = substr(noquote(get(date_col))[!is.na(noquote(get(date_col)))],1,4))][]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last two statements return an error message:

```
dat[,`:=`(paste0(date_col, "_year", sep="") = substr(noquote(get(date_col))[!is.na(noquote(get(date_col)))],1,4))][]
```

> ```
> Error: unexpected '=' in "dat[,`:=`(paste0(date_col, "_year", sep="") ="
> ```

```
dat[,`:=`(noquote(paste0(date_col, "_year", sep="")) = substr(noquote(get(date_col))[!is.na(noquote(get(date_col)))],1,4))][]
```

> ```
> Error: unexpected '=' in "dat[,`:=`(noquote(paste0(date_col, "_year", sep="")) ="
> ```

The correct syntax for calling the `:=()` function is:

```
dat[, `:=`(paste0(date_col, "_year", sep = ""), 
           substr(noquote(get(date_col))[!is.na(noquote(get(date_col)))], 1, 4))][]
dat[, `:=`(noquote(paste0(date_col, "_year", sep = "")), 
           substr(noquote(get(date_col))[!is.na(noquote(get(date_col)))], 1, 4))][]
```

i.e., replace `=` by `,`.

---

However, assignment syntax and right hand side are far too complicated.

The `order_date` column is already of class `Date`:

```
str(dat)
```

> ```
> Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':    5 obs. of  3 variables:
>  $ one       : int  1 2 3 4 5
>  $ two       : int  1 2 3 4 5
>  $ order_date: Date, format: "2015-01-01" "2015-02-01" ...
>  - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr>
> ```

In order to extract the year, `year()` function can be used (either from the `data.table` package or the `lubridate` package whatever is loaded last), so no conversion back to character and extraction of the year string is required:

```
date_col = "order_date"
dat[, paste0(date_col, "_year") := lapply(.SD, year), .SDcols = date_col][]
```

> ```
>    one two order_date order_date_year
> 1:   1   1 2015-01-01            2015
> 2:   2   2 2015-02-01            2015
> 3:   3   3 2015-03-01            2015
> 4:   4   4 2015-04-01            2015
> 5:   5   5 2015-05-01            2015
> ```

Alternatively,

```
dat[, paste0(date_col, "_year") := year(get(date_col))][]
dat[, `:=`(paste0(date_col, "_year"), year(get(date_col)))][]
```

work as well.

Answer (score 1):

The *set* function is nice for doing this. Quicker than setting inside the data.table too. Is this what you are after?
http://brooksandrew.github.io/simpleblog/articles/advanced-data-table/#fast-looping-with-set

```
library(data.table)
dat = data.table(one = 1:5, two = 1:5, 
                 order_date = lubridate::ymd("2015-01-01","2015-02-01","2015-03-01",
                           "2015-04-01","2015-05-01"))
dat
date_col = "order_date"

year_col <- paste0(date_col, "_year", sep="")
set(dat, j = year_col, value = substr(dat[[date_col]], 1, 4) )
```